# Vue.js how to use attributes on slots

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-slot

is it possible to set attributes on a slot and the element from the parent gets these attributes?

Parent

```html
<vDropdown>
  <button slot="button">new button</button>
  <ul>content</ul>
</vDropdown>
```

Dropdown.vue

```html
<div>
  <slot name="button" aria-haspopup="true">
    //fallback
    <button aria-haspopup="true">Default Button</button>
  </slot>
  <div id="name" :aria-expanded="expanded">
    <slot />
  </div>
</div>
```

the output for the button is without any attributes...

```html
<div>
  <button>new button</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <ul>content</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Use [Scoped Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots)**

**Step 1.** In the parent, update the old [deprecated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Deprecated-Syntax) slot targeting syntax `slot="button"` to the `v-slot` directive:

<sub>*Parent.vue*</sub>

```html
...
<template v-slot:button>                   ✅
  <button>new button</button>
</template>
...
```

```html
<button slot="button">new button</button>  ❌
```

<sup>*How to target a slot in Vue 2.6.0+*</sup>

**Step 2.** Next, understand that any attribute bindings you add to a `<slot>` tag will become available to any slotted content placed there (these are called "slot props"):

<sub>*Dropdown.vue*</sub>

```html
<slot name="button" :aria-haspopup="true">
```

**Step 3.** Vue automatically creates an object containing every binding from Step 2, and passes that to the `v-slot` expression, i.e. `slotProps` below.  You can then use the special `v-bind=""` syntax to spread all those bindings onto the button:

<sub>*Parent.vue* updated</sub>

```html
<template v-slot:button="slotProps">
  <button v-bind="slotProps">new button</button>
</template>
```

Here's a demo, but sadly it requires a hack using two hyphens when you do this with a kebab-case attribute.  I'll plan to submit an issue for this in the Vue GitHub repo.

```js
Vue.component('dropdown', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <slot name="button" aria--haspopup="true">
      <button aria-haspopup="true">Default Button</button>
    </slot>
    <div id="name" :aria-expanded="expanded">
      <slot />
    </div>
  </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      expanded: true
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
});
```

```css
.aria-haspopup {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <dropdown>
    <template v-slot:button="slotProps">
      <button v-bind="slotProps">new button</button>
    </template>
    <ul>content</ul>
  </dropdown>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for you detailed answer, but if you inspect your code snippet the aria attribute 'aria-haspopup' is missing. My intention was just to place some attributes on the slot, without adding more complexity. So I think I will just parse the $el for the first button and place the attributes via js.

Comment: I updated the demo, I had misread the question as a class rather than an attribute.  It works great... except for attributes with a hyphen, so I submitted an issue to the Vue repo.  I'll leave the answer up in hopes that they fix it (and I showed a workaround in the demo).